# mybatis interceptor redundant wrap

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I use mybatis interceptor to intercept before update sql operation, but now all query operations also go into "plugin" method.
I don't known why this happens. what i expect is only update operation go into this method , i think it is unnecessary to wrap target when query operation which may takes some time and loss performance.
Does any one know the reason? or is there some solutions to avoid wrap when query sql operations?

```
@Intercepts({@Signature(type = Executor.class, method = "update", args = {MappedStatement.class, Object.class})})
@Slf4j
public class OperationTrackInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    
    @Override
    public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        ......
       ........
    }

    @Override
    public Object plugin(Object target) {
        if(target instanceof Executor){
            Object wrap = Plugin.wrap(target, this);
            return wrap;
        }else {
            return target;
        }
    }
}
```

**I want to code like below:**

```
    @Override
        public Object plugin(Object target) {
             if(current operations is "QUERY" ){
               return target
             
           }     
           .......
           .......
           .......
 }
```